# Array is not working as expected in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am running into a very strange issue.

I have a function which prints the columns name of a given database table from MySql.

```
function getColoumn() {

    //replace it with your host normally it could be localhost
    $hostname='localhost';
    //mysql user name
    $username='admin_datauser';
    //mysql user password
    $password='iCoq4KrJM8';
    //connect to the mysql server
    $ss = mysql_pconnect($hostname, $username, $password) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
    //select a database on the mysql server
    //please change as you like the database name
    mysql_select_db('admin_data');

    //SHOW COLUMNS FROM TABLENAME
    $query=mysql_query('SHOW COLUMNS FROM user') or die(mysql_error());


    foreach($fields as $key=>$field){
    echo '"'.$field->Field.'", '; // print each field name

    }
}
```

The output looks like below-

```
"id", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "address", "country", "city", "state", "phone_number", "fax", "image", "datecreated", "dateupdated", "Company", "token",
```

I have another array variable where the current static values are like below-

```
$searchArray = array("first_name","last_name","email","address","country","city","state","phone_number","fax","image");
```

I need to use the function's variable in this $searchArray. I tried calling the variable in the arrya but it doesn't work in any way.

Any help please??

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: And after a `mysql_query()` which runs the query and creates a result set. You have to read rows from that resultset with something like `$fields = mysql_fetch_object();` Normally written in a `while () {}` loop

Comment: This function does not look like it should work. `$fields` is undefined unless I'm missing something.

Comment: The main problem appears to be this: you need your function to return an array, but instead it prints a string and returns null. Just replace the `echo` with something that puts the field name into an array, and when you've gotten them all, return the array.

Comment: Is this ALL your relevant code, or have you missed bits out. **I do hate having to do the 20 questions dance before getting to the real question**

Answer (score 1):

first of all you shouldn't use `mysql_` functions anymore since they are deprecated and prone to SQL injections. rather use PHP's own [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) libraries.

then it's much easier to directly add the elements to your array in the `foreach` loop:

```
$searchArray = array();

foreach($fields as $key=>$field){
    $searchArray[]= $field->Field;
}
```

**note:** the `[]=` operator in PHP acts similar to the `+=` operator. but instead of adding to a number value, it adds elements to an array.

Comment: And again, where does `$fields` come from?? You missed that OP is not reading the result set

Comment: @RiggsFolly true, but OP says that "output looks like below" - which can't be true if s/he is not reading the resultset.

Comment: @RiggsFolly so I am guessing it's just a copy-paste error from OP - where should the output magically come from otherwise?